# How can I launch an Activity from different parts of an application?

Tags: android

So I have 2 activities which are part of the user login process in my application. I want the flexibility to launch login process from different parts of the application and then go two different points (kind of like a redirect URL thing). How can I achieve this ?
One way which I can think of is send some extra data along with the intent which is launching process to point to where it should go.

Example

```
A->login1->login2->B
X->login1->login2->Y
```

Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the login activity with `startActivityForResult`. In login1 and login2, make you login process, then use `setResult` (OK or NOK) and then `finish`, so you end up in the Activity you were before starting the login1.

You'll receive the result in onActivityResult, where you'll test the result value, and act accordingly (logged in or not).

More on this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: Thanks ! I knew about the concept but did not think of using the login process as means of returning a sucess/failure result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions could look like below:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login1.class);
        intent.putExtra("redirectToComponent", 
                new ComponentName(this, B.class));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

class Login1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login2.class);
        intent.putExtra("redirectToComponent", 
                getIntent().getParcelableExtra("redirectToComponent"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

class Login2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        ComponentName component = (ComponentName) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
                "redirectToComponent");
        if(component != null) {
            Intent redirectIntent = new Intent();
            redirectIntent.setComponent(component);
            startActivity(redirectIntent);
        }
    }
}

class B extends Activity {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass name(string) of desired activity to start or redirect after login in intent for login activity using **putExtra** and add a condition after login to check which string denotes which activity to redirect.

example:

```
A->(**putExtra("B")**)->login1->login2->(**getExtra, condition**)->B
X->(**putExtra("Y")**)->login1->login2->(**getExtra, condition**)->Y
```

Comment: I figured this much, but this is not a very good method because it will require the login activities to be updated everytime I plan to launch them from a different place. This is why I asked the question.